# Can't run a HelloWorld Go program in Docker on Intel Mac

Tags: docker, macos, go

I am getting a `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error` while trying to run a helloWorld on Intel Mac. Runs fine outside of docker.

`hello.go`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu
VOLUME ["/data"]
WORKDIR /data
ENTRYPOINT ["/data/hello"]
```

```
$ go build ./hello.go 
$ docker build -t aaa . 
$ docker run -v ${PWD}:/data  aaa

standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                      
Darwin ###-MBP 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:45:05 PDT 2022; #####/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Start by fixing you `go build` command, use `go build -o hello` (make sure to properly set up your module). Then check what the generated hello is by running `file hello` locally and in Docker. Your Docker is Linux, not Mac/Darwin. You might have to cross-compile for docker like `GOOS=linux go build`.

Answer (score 5):

You are building a binary for macOS and attempting to run it on a Linux container.

There are two things you can do to fix this:

- add steps to the Dockerfile to compile your code in the container itself
- when compiling on the Mac locally, cross compile it for Linux by setting the environment variable `GOOS=linux`